# Does non-commutativity of group imply $|G/Z(G)| \geq 4$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a non-abelian group. Then how can I show that $|G/Z(G)| \geq 4$, where $Z(G)= \left\{ g \in G : \forall h \in G , gh = hg \right\}$. Is it that $G / Z(G)$ is a non-abelian group and as a result has order $\geq 4$?

Comment: Note that if your approach would work then you would have to have $|G/Z(G)| \geq 6$ as the symmetric group on three points is the smallest non-abelian group. However, the dihedral group of order $8$ shows that the inequality is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

We use the following theorem:

> If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Thus if $G$ is non-abelian, we see that $|G/Z(G)| \in \{1,2,3\}$ is impossible (because groups of order $1,2,3$ are always cyclic).

Hence, $|G/Z(G)|\geq 4$.

---

We can't do better than this. Take the dihedral group $D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^4 = b^2 = 1, bab = a^{-1}\rangle$. This is a non-abelian group with center $\{1, a^2\}$ and thus $|G/Z(G)| = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian